# How to change the expiration date of binlog files?

Tags: mysql, configuration, ubuntu, logs

I have a server with Ubuntu 18.04 and MySQL 8.0.11

I have binlog files in `/var/lib/mysql` that make several GO and my server will soon saturate.

How to change the expiration date of binlog files ?

If I go to :

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

The file contains :

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

If I go to :

```
nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

The file contains :

```
[mysql]
```

If I go to :

```
nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

The file contains :

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

I can not find the file to configure. Is it safe for the database to change the timeout ?

Comment: An idea please ?

Answer (score 2):

> How to change the expiration date of binlog files ?

To purge binary logs prior to a binary log file or prior to a particular date, use [purge binary logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html) statement.

To set an expiration period for binary logs, use [binlog_expire_logs_seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds). I would recommend to keep this more than 2 days, whether or not you have replication enabled.

> I can not find the file to configure.

To see the order in which MySQL looks at the configuration files, run the following:

```
mysqld --help --verbose | grep -A 2 "Default options are read from"
```

If you also want to see what values the different variables would take on start, remove the `grep` part.

For a variable whose value is specified multiple times in the configuration files, or multiple times in the same file, the last value would be considered by MySQL. Some of these configuration files may not already be present, in which case you can create them on your own, and under `[mysqld]` in the configuration file, add the parameters you want to set.

> Is it safe for the database to change the timeout ?

Yes, it is safe if there is no replication involved. Even if a slave does exist, if all the logs that are to be deleted have been already processed and executed by the slave, it is safe to delete those logs from master.

Comment: Well, I put 600 seconds yesterday. Should I restore?

Comment: Did you use 600 seconds for `binlog_expire_logs_seconds`?

Comment: yes 600 seconds for binlog_expire_logs_seconds I only have one server, there is no replication. I read in other questions that you have to put 0

Comment: Do you know if I have to restore my server?

Comment: A value of 0 for `binlog_expire_logs_seconds` would mean that automatic removal  of binary logs will not happen if `expire_logs_days` is also not set. `expire_logs_days` is a deprecated variable in MySQL 8.0. I would recommend you go through the official MySQL docs for answers to such questions.  [binlog_expire_logs_seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds), [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days)

Comment: @ML61 in which file did you changed.?

Answer (score 0):

`log_bin = 0` to turn off writing to the binlogs at all.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the *command line / terminal*, connected to the server with **root** privileges `SET PERSIST` or `SET GLOBAL` is the command to use, you can put directly the value in seconds or the conversion math operation in parentheses:

```
mysql> SET PERSIST binlog_expire_logs_seconds = (60*60*24*3);
```

... this is to set the variable to 3 days *(in seconds)*.

You can see more related commands in verge's answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/306954/163431.

Related official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-persisting-configuration-variables/.

Comment: ...afterwards you can: `mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_expire_logs_seconds'` to verify the value was set correctly